# How to install a new font in SharePoint?

Tags: wss-3.0

I have a new font to be installed on Sharepoint?
Can someone guide me how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're wanting to do is to embed fonts in your pages.

You can do this with the Masterpage, and specify in CSS the filename of the font you want to load. Make sure the file you want to load is accessable globally (so put it in the LAYOUTS folder in the 12 hive, so you can access the file using url:(/_layouts/your_fonts.eot))

Read up on this article on embedding fonts into web pages:

http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,1306847,00.asp

Answer (score 2):

As SharePoint is (mostly) a web application, you either have to have the font server-side (to generate an image with text inside) or ensure that the client(s) will also have the font installed (in that case you don't need to do anything on the server, thus "nothing to install server side")

You should give us more explanations of what you're trying to achieve. If you want to use a special font in your web application, you can implement something like sIFR (flash) or Cufon/TypeFace (javascript). If you want your document to have a specific font, that's tricky because AFAIK, there is no way to embed a custom font in a doc (but I might be wrong).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply!. I have a TTF font (indian regional language font) which I need in Sharepoint so that some users can use it. i.e. As we have 'Times New Roman' font I want my regional font to also display in description field. Is this possible? How do I install it? Thx

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by not replacing existing layouts but by making a custom font available from the heading / body font-drop-down lists in Site Settings > Site Themes:

- Install the font(s) on your server. (Actually, I am not sure whether this step is really needed. Theoretically, the new font has to be installed locally on the viewer's machine, only).
- Create a theme with the new font(s) included. See especially step 6,7
  and 8 [here](http://sp365.co.uk/2011/07/creating-a-theme-for-sharepoint-2010-using-powerpoint/). Alternatively, you could also download one of your existing themes
  and edit it accordingly.
- Upload your theme (see reference above).

When I found this question and its answers here, I was not looking for (backend) modifications to have the font available. AFAIK, the above answers are no solution where (end)users can decide to use the font or not.